# Combinatorics problem: how many possibilities are there after some permutations?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

This question has an example part and a general part.

**Example Setting:**

We are given a sequence $X$ of hexadecimal datapoints with length $10\\$:
$$X=x_1,x_2,...,x_{10}$$
where $x_i \in \{0,1,...,9,A,B,...,F\}$

We call a sequence a **match** if at least 7 of 10 values of the sequence corrsepond to $X$. That means that we $15^3\cdot{10\choose 7} + 15^2\cdot {10\choose 8}+ 15\cdot {10\choose 9}+ {10\choose 10}= 415276$  combinations that we can call a match.

**Questions about the example: modifying the sequence**

Suppose we have some random **match** $X'$ (so 1 out of 415276).

**E1.)** Say we modify $X'$ such that we randomly change the value of the first datapoint (so the value of the first datapoint becomes equiprobably a $0,1,...,A,B,...$ or $F$). What is the possibility that the sequence continues to be a match?

**E2.)** The same question, but then when we randomly change the first 2 values of the sequence.

**E3.)** The same question, but then when we randomly change the first 3 values of the sequence.

**E4.)** etc.

***General questions***

Given a sequence $Y=y_1,...y_m$ of $m$ hexadecimal datapoints. We call a sequence of $m$ hexadecimal datapoints a match if $n<m$ of the datapoints correspond to the datapoints of $Y$.

**G0.)** How many possible matches are there?

Suppose we are given a match $Y'$ (so at least $n$ of the $m$ datapoints correspond to sequence $Y$).

**G1.)** Say we modify $Y'$ such that we randomly change the first $x$ datapoints (equiprobably). What is the possibility that our modified sequence remains to be a match?

Comment: Your computation of the number of matches is not correct.  There are not just $10 \choose 9$ that match in $9$ places, because the non-matching one has $15$ possibilities.  Similarly, there are$15^3{10 \choose 7}$ strings that match in exactly $7$ places.

Comment: For your questions, I would compute the chance that each number of correspondences still matches.  When changing just one character, if you started with 8,9, or 10 correspondences, it will still match.  It can only stop matching if you started with 7 and change one of those 7.

Comment: @RossMillikan Thanks, I forgot to think about that. Updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll do the first one, which should show you the approach.  $405000$ of the $415276$ have exactly $7$ positions agreeing.  All the other $10276$ will still match.  Of those, $121500$ disagree in the first position, so changing it cannot destroy the match.  The remaining $283500$ will still match with probability $\frac1{16}$, because we might not change the value.  The expected number of remaining matches is $10276+121500+283500/16=151369 \frac 34$.  The chance the match is destroyed is then $1-\frac {151369 \frac 34}{415276}$ or about $63.55\%$

Added after the question edit:  If you force the change to not match the original sequence, you get rid of the $283500/16$ term which reduces the number considerably.  It does make the calculation easier.  In your edit you don't discuss how many positions are needed for a match out of your $m$.  But if $m=100, x=25$, and we need agreement on $60$ to be a match, you can survive if you start with $60$ and none are in the first $25$, which is $15^{40}{75 \choose 60}$ ways, or ... start with $62$ with at most $2$ in the first $25$, which is $15^{38}({75\choose 62}+{75 \choose 61}{25 \choose 1}+{75 \choose 60}{25 \choose 2})$, or ....

Comment: As I have to program this (java or matlab) problem, Im looking for a simpler approximation of the possibilities that a given match continues to be a match. So I hope you can answer the following problem as well (then I'll accept your answer!).

Suppose we have a match sequence and instead 'randomly change' the first $x$ values, we just change them to values so that all of them have different values compared to our original sequence. Then we calculate the probabilities again. Is this a 'good' approximation to solve this problem (applied to sequences of lengths of $m>100$, and about $x= 0.25m$

Comment: Thank you so much. Final question is: what happens with the error of the approximation for bigger $m$ (and $x$ and $n$ growing proportionally with $m$). For example, do we get a (relatively) bigger or smaller error for $m=1000$, $x=250$, agreement of $600$ to be a match comparing to your example?

And what if the data is not hexadecimal but binary?

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: I misread the problem and didn’t catch that the change is not necessarily a change, so my solution answers a different question (the situation where the $x_i$ is definitely changed to one of the $15$ other digits). Hopefully this is still helpful. You can proceed as I did, but with three kinds of matches: $7$-matches that do not include $x_1$ in the matched set; $7$-matches that do include $x_1$ in the matched set, and more-matches.

---

If $X$ is a match, call $X$ a *$7$-match* if exactly $7$ terms are the same and a  *more-match* if more than $7$ are. (Note that every match is one or the other of these two kinds of match, and no sequence can be both a $7$-match and a more-match.) Figure out how many of each kind there are; say there are $m_7$ 7-matches and $m_8$ more-matches (of the $m_7+m_8$ matches among all sequences).

Now calculate a useful conditional probability: Let $p_7$ be the probability that a sequence is a $7$-match, given that it is a match. It’s easy to see that $p_7=\frac{m_7}{m_7+m_8}$. Observe that $p_8=1-p_7$ is the probability that a sequence known to be a match is a more-match.

If $X$ is a more-match, the probability that it remains a match when $x_1$ is changed is $1$.

If $X$ is a 7-match, the probability that it remains a match is $0.3$, because there is a $0.3$ chance that $x_1$ is not one of the exactly $7$ items that match, and it is then and only then that $X$ remains a match when $x_1$ is changed.

Therefore, by the law of total probability, the probability that a match remains a match when $x_1$ is changed is $0.3\cdot p_7+1\cdot p_8$.

I’ll leave it to you to find $m_7$ and $m_8$ so you end up with a numerical answer. You should also be able to generalize this to the situation when $2$ or $3$ of the $x_i$ are changed. So long as you don’t change enough of the $x_i$ to raise the possibility that the new matching items are not a subset of the original ones, the problem stays relatively simple. Because a match requires $7$ equal items, there are only three others than can be equal, and you would have to change $4$ of the $x_i$ for that situation to come up.